# How to solve these recursive linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently trying to understand a paper for a time step methods. In the analysis of the method, the method is written in a recursive form $X_{n+1} = A X_n, X_n = (d_n, \Delta t v_n, \Delta t^2 a_n)^T$, where $d$ are the displacements, $v$ the velocities and $a$ the accelerations (see [equation (6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvISa.png)).

Later, that equation gets written into a difference equation, $d_{n+1} - 2A_1 d_n + A_2 d_{n+1} - A_3 d_{n-2} = 0$ where $A_1 = 1/2 \operatorname{trace} (A), A_2 =$ sum of principal minors of $A$ and $A_3 = \det(A)$ ([equation (9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUFd8.png)) which does not contain any $v$ or $a$. How can I proof this step?

Comment: What are you solving for? $X_k$ or $A$ or something else?

Comment: I think solving was the wrong expression. How can I rearrange the equation (6) into equation (9)?

Comment: Can you please write the equations into formulas in the question using MathJax and LaTeX? I can't see the formula in the pictures.

Comment: If I am right, the speed and acceleration are just replaced by the backward finite differences of the displacements.

Comment: $X_{n+1} = A X_n, X_n = (d_n, \Delta t v_n, \Delta t^2 a_n)^T$ is the recursive formulation. I want to write this into $d_{n+1} - 2A_1 d_n + A_2 d_{n+1} - A_3 d_{n-2}$ where $A_1 = 1/2 trace (A), A_2 =$ sum of pricipal minors of A and $A_3 = det(A)$